# PHP code not being executed within HTML file

Tags: php

I have a file with the following code block inside some of the page html:

```
<input name="appname" type="text" value="<?php Load('appname'); ?>" placeholder="Your App Name" />
```

which calls this function:

```
<?php
// Load cookie values 
function Load($item) {
    $item = strtolower($item);
    if(!$_COOKIE['appsite_'.$item]) return null;
    return $_COOKIE['appsite_'.$item];
}
?>
```

The function is at the top of the HTML file, the cookies are created but for some reason the code inside the input HTML markup is not being executed.

I can access the value of the cookie by doing the following just beneath the function:

```
$item = "appname";
echo $_COOKIE['w8appsite_'.$item];
```

It seems like the PHP code lower down the file is just not being executed?

Comment: HTML and PHP are not the same.

Comment: Is a simple return statement of a function sufficient to echo out the contents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<input name="appname" type="text" value="<?php echo Load('appname'); ?>" placeholder="Your App Name" />
```

You need to `echo` strings in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You are setting cookie `$_COOKIE['w8appsite_appname']` and in the function checking for `$_COOKIE['appsite_appname']` which will always return `null`.